# Filtering dataframes in named list based on the name of each dataframe

Tags: r, filter, lapply

I have multiple data frames in a named list, reproducible example below:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
  numbers = sample(1:10),
  boolean = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    letters = sample(LETTERS,10),
    numbers = sample(1:10),
    boolean = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
dataframes <- list(df1, df2)
names(dataframes) <- c("yes","no")
```

How can I filter the first data frame to include all rows with "yes" and the second data frame to include rows containing "no".

I tried:

```
lapply(dataframes, function(x) filter(x, boolean==names(x))
```

But that didn't work, just gave me empty data frames for both. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: Could you copy and paste current and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the *dataframes* names

```
lapply(names(dataframes),function(x) dplyr::filter(dataframes[[x]],boolean==x))

[[1]]
  numbers boolean
  1       3     yes
  2       4     yes
  3       7     yes
  4       8     yes
  5      10     yes

[[2]]
  letters numbers boolean
  1       Y       5      no
  2       F       6      no
  3       P       4      no
  4       C       2      no
  5       Z      10      no
  6       I       8      no
  7       X       7      no
  8       V       3      no
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can loop through the `list` with `imap` and use `.y` i.e. names of the `list` for `filter`ing

```
library(tidyverse)
imap(dataframes,  ~ .x %>% 
                        filter(boolean == .y))
#$yes
#  numbers boolean
#1       3     yes
#2       4     yes
#3       7     yes
#4       8     yes
#5      10     yes

#$no
#  letters numbers boolean
#1       Y       5      no
#2       F       6      no
#3       P       4      no
#4       C       2      no
#5       Z      10      no
#6       I       8      no
#7       X       7      no
#8       V       3      no
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`'s `Map` and `subset` we can do

```
Map(function(x, y) subset(x, boolean == y), x = dataframes, y = names(dataframes))
#$yes
#  numbers boolean
#1       3     yes
#2       4     yes
#3       7     yes
#4       8     yes
#5      10     yes

#$no
#  letters numbers boolean
#1       Y       5      no
#2       F       6      no
#3       P       4      no
#4       C       2      no
#5       Z      10      no
#6       I       8      no
#7       X       7      no
#8       V       3      no
```